# How to change the date format?

Tags: anno-2070

I'm new to Anno 2070 and started playing today, but one of the first things I noticed is that the date format is all wrong. The game is in English as is my OS, however the game uses the date format MM/dd/yyyy whereas my OS is set to yyyy-MM-dd. Any idea how to correct the date format that Anno 2070 uses? It might sound a little over the top but I actually find it very hard to read the dates in the correct order with this confusing format.

P.S. Everyone knows yyyy-MM-dd (ISO 8601) is [*the* correct way to write numeric dates](http://xkcd.com/1179/) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to change the date format within Anno 2070. The date format is not inherited from any operating system level settings and the designers of the game chose to use the date format of MM/dd/yyyy in game.